# How can I track opening and closing event of NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa, events

I did try `– windowDidExpose:` but it didn't work. What do I have to try for this?

My window is a utility window.

-- edit for more clarity --

What I want are:

`viewWillAppear`
`viewWillDisappear`
`viewDidLoad`
`viewDidUnload`

in Cocoa Touch.

Comment: `windowDidExpose:` is for a window that is already ordered in being revealed by other windows being ordered behind it.

Comment: Oh thanks for clarification. It was hard to know with only description in reference.

Comment: The description is better for the notification that that method corresponds to: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWindowDidExposeNotification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `windowDidClose:`, but that probably only refers to closing; if you're sending your window an `orderOut:` message, I don't think that counts.

You probably need to either just track it from whatever code you're ordering the window in and out from, or subclass the window's class and override methods like `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` and `orderOut:` (whatever you're using, at least) to post custom notifications before calling up to `super`.

Comment: No delegate message for this? It's hard to believe! It seems not a good idea subclassing and overriding all of related methods because I can't sure which methods should be overridden for this...

Comment: Hence the first suggestion: Track it from whatever code of yours tells the window to order in or out. The only way it could order out not by your hand would be the user closing it, and there's `windowDidClose:` for that.

Comment: The problem is that "whatever code you're ordering the window in and out from" isn't the only code that might cause the window to close.  For example, the window may have a close button.

Comment: @augurar: Hence “The only way it could order out not by your hand would be the user closing it, and there's `windowDidClose:` for that.”

Comment: @PeterHosey You're right, I somehow missed that part of your comment.

Answer (score 7):

Very old question, but only for documentation purpose:

---

**Track open:**
In your windows controller override the method:

```
-(void)showWindow:(id)sender
{
    //add this for track the window close
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(windowWillClose)
                                                 name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [super showWindow:sender];
    //do here what you want...
}
```

**Track close:**
Implement the method

```
-(void)windowWillClose
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    //do here what you want...
}
```

Comment: Is it fine not to having one `id` parameter for notification observer?

Comment: it is not wrong but yes, if you want receive an object, for example the sending window, you must change your notification observer.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift**

**Track open**: In your windows controller override the method:

```
override func showWindow(sender: AnyObject?) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(windowWillClose), name: NSWindowWillCloseNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

**Track close**: Implement the method:

```
func windowWillClose() -> Void {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);
        //Do here what you want..
    }
```

Comment: For Swift 4: 
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(windowWillClose), name: NSWindow.willCloseNotification, object: window)`
and
`@objc func windowWillClose() -> Void {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        //Do here what you want..
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a hack for dealing with this. There is no notification that *signals* that a window has been put on screen, but there's a notification that's pretty much guaranteed to be *sent* when a window is put on screen. I'm speaking of `NSWindowDidUpdateNotification`, which indicates that a window has refreshed itself.

Of course, it's not *only* sent when the window appears—it's sent every time the window updates. Needless to say, this notification is sent a *lot* more than once. So you want to watch for it the first time, do your thing, and ignore any subsequent notifications. In my case, I wanted to add a sheet to a window that another part of my app would order in later. So I did something like this:

```
__block id observer = [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:NSWindowDidUpdateNotification object:window queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [self showSetupSheet];
    [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter removeObserver:observer];
}];
```

There's no particular reason you would have to use a block-based observer—a method-based observer would work just as well.